# Microsoft Access 2007 Lags after Print Job

Tags: sql, database, performance, ms-access

I am new to Microsoft Access.

I added some queries to an old and existing database (.accdb) using Microsoft Access 2007.

I created two forms in Access, and two buttons in the Switchboard.

Whenever the buttons are clicked, I load the form which was created using the SQL query through the Form Wizard.

However, now whenever I print, the particular form which has the print button using the following old existing code.

```
 Private Sub CmdPrintInv_Click()
On Error GoTo Err_CmdPrintInv_Click

    Dim stDocName As String
    Dim sqlstr As String

    sqlstr = "InvType='" & InvType.Value & "' AND InvNo='" & InvNo & "'"

    stDocName = "R-Invoice"
    DoCmd.OpenReport stDocName, acNormal, , sqlstr

Exit_CmdPrintInv_Click:
    Exit Sub

Err_CmdPrintInv_Click:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Resume Exit_CmdPrintInv_Click

End Sub
```

[image: The PRINT form window, the orange outlined button has the code above attached to it.]

Previously, the database was working fine after clicking print. The other buttons were responsive.

Now, the database lags, particularly the window attached. Whenever I try to click other buttons, they are not responsive.

Any advise would help me out.

Comment: Not enough information. What changed between the time when it worked and the time when it became slow? Was it by chance a conversion to ACCDB?

Comment: Hi David, 
Thanks for reading through my problem. I managed to solve it by realizing that it became slow only after i enabled the Navigation Page in Access preferences. Apparently, whenever you enable the Navigation pane, any button action will make it unresponsive.